# newman cli version 4.2.3 and 4.2.0 giving wrong result but postman return correct result

Tags: npm, postman, postman-collection-runner

Tests in postman passes as the api returns the 200 ok response, but the same postman collection in newmnan cli returns failed assertions as results even for the passed test (200 ok).

1. Test for checking response to return 200 status code passed in postman but failed in newman cli with the failure details as :

   Status code is 200
   expected { Object (id, _details, ...) } to have property 'code'
   at assertion:0 in test-script.
2. the postman collection had 3 API's but in the table summary, it shows only no of iterations, test scripts and the no of assertions which failed. It does not track the no of the request made as shown in the snapshot attached.
   [image: NEWMAN CLI RESPONSE SNAPSHOT]

Comment: this is what my test script consists of : pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

Comment: Can you attach the collection JSON to the question so people can see the file that Newman is using.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured out after a while that the request itself was not getting triggered as the endpoint were secured with 2-way ssl and there were certificate path mismatch in newman command i was triggering .It is resolved now . Can anyone please mark it resolved.